# Beginner questions on some SMD components in phone motherboard

Tags: surface-mount, motherboard, smartphones

I'm trying to understand smartphone motherboard components and have a few questions that might be easy for some of you to answer. Please refer to the attached image for the question numbers:

[image]

1. Are these all capacitors?
2. What is that tiny component that was accidentally moved/damaged by repairmen I guess.
3. What are these black and silver components? Inductor coils?
4. What is this component? It's blackish in nature than how it appears in this photo.

Comment: Why target smartphones for your learning?

Comment: Fundamentally this is a bit tricky because of the lack of markings or distinctive features - everything with two terminals is either "black blob" or "grey-brown blob", and the latter are usually capacitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They do look like rather "gigantic" (for phone integration) caps, yes. But they could also be something else – like a whole filter. But, seeing them in this context, yeah, caps.
2. An SMD 0201 component. That's pretty much all one can say with certainty. From here, it looks like it might be some resistor (totally unknown value), but it might also be a low-value capacitor.
3. Probably yes, but again, since one can't look inside SMD components... But, if they are, then the closest IC is a switch-mode power supply controller (or has one built in). If you know that's the case: here's your inductors.
4. an SMD resistor, capacitor, miniature ferrite bead, diode, or other component.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention the scale: the width of the image would be ~2.5 inches. And for (3), appears to be PM660 IC nearby, if that gives more clarity? For (4), I'm asking because this appears missing after another repair attempt elsewhere. I'm going to send this to a specialized repair center now. (some very important data is in there)

Comment: @Drek A little googling tells me the PM660 is a mobile phone SoC produced by Qualcomm. The datasheet doesn't seem to be easily accessible however. I did find this product overview brochure though!
This seems to confirm Marcus's thoughts: the PM660 does have internal boost regulators which would require those small chip inductors. The PM660 is doing most of the work here, namely the camera interface, display driving, and wired/wireless interface.
https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/34909/snapdragon-660-mobile-hdk-product-brief_87-pd101-1.pdf